# format date as long inside reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
var Post = React.createClass({


render: function () {
    return (
      <li key={ this.props.message.uid }>
        <div className="avatar">
          <img src={ this.props.message.user.avatar } className="img-circle"/>
        </div>
        <div className="messages">
          <p>{ this.props.message.content }</p>
          <span className="date">{ "@"+this.props.message.user.login + " • " }</span>
          <span className="date timeago" title={ this.props.message.createdAt }>
            { this.props.message.createdAt }
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
      )
  }
});
```

turns out that the `createdAt` is a string like `1451589259845` and I want to format the date. How can I do that on ReactJS? I tried put `new Date()` inside the brackets but got an error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just prepare all your data in the JS context, before you start your return, the same way you write any other JS. Then you can simply template in single var names and everything is both much clearer, and much easier:

```
render() {
  const { createdAt } = this.props.message;
  const createdDate = (new Date(createdAt)).toString();
  return (
    ...
    <span ...>{ createdDate }</span>
    ...
  );
}
```

And you don't necessarily need the base `toString()`, there are quite a few ways you can do the string formatting. `Date` has a number of them built in (like `toLocaleString` or `toUTCString`), or you can use the [DateTime formatter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) built into JS for even more precise control over the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. My table shows now this format:
Fri Mar 23 2018 10:17:55 GMT-0500 (SA Pacific Standard Time)

Answer (score 18):

You could just run the regular JavaScript New Date(). However, I would strongly recommend using momentjs, as it seems to be more in line with what you are trying to do.

On the command line do:

`npm install moment --save`

Then in your code either `var moment = require("moment");` or
`import moment from "moment";` depending on whether you are using ES6 or not.

After that, I would run code like so.

`var timeAgo = moment(this.props.message.createdAt).fromNow()`

`<span className="date timeago" title={ timeAgo }>
{ timeAgo }</span>`

Also, it may seem like a huge pain to install a package to do this, but moment is really nice and I would highly recommend it. The reason I recommended it is that it **humanizes** times. Like for instance, the fromNow() formatting makes it say 30 seconds ago, 4 days ago, or 3 months ago. It makes it sound like a person wrote it and it doesn't display tons of unnecessary info unless specified. I mean, most people don't want to know how many minutes and seconds ago it was if it was several hours ago. So, I recommended this library for those reasons. Feel free to use vanilla JS though if you prefer, I just find that moment is very nice for presentational purposes and let's me avoid having to write tons of math functions to display months, etc.

Comment: That is of course assuming, that you wanted to list how long ago it was created, but it seemed to me that that is what you were attempting.

Answer (score 15):

Want this format?

> Wed, May 30, 2018`

Just declare

```
const DATE_OPTIONS = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
```

And then in your React JS code

```
{(new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US', DATE_OPTIONS)}
```

> toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date
>
> [Source and more options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 7):

You can use Intl.DateTimeFormat to control over the time formatting. The [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) object is a constructor for objects that enable the language-sensitive date and time formatting.

```
       <span className="date timeago" title={ this.props.message.createdAt }>
            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { 
                month: 'long', 
                day: '2-digit',
                year: 'numeric', 
            }).format(new Date(this.props.message.createdAt))}
      </span>
```

It will result in an example: "17 December 2019" format.

Answer (score 2):

In plain JS WITHOUT moment.js

```
    const dateFromData= "06/15/1990" //string type
    const formatDate = (dateString: string) => {
    const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = { //Typescript ways of adding the type
      year: "numeric",
      month: "long",
      day: "numeric",
    };
      return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString([], options);
    };
    console.log(formatDate(dateFromData)); // output will be: June 15, 1990
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up all your answers are correct but I follow this code. Can I format my dates before it will pass down to my array using `Moment`. But the start only gives me an `undefined value`

```
const data = upcomingWork.map(u => ({
  id: u.id,
  title: u.title,
  start: Moment(u.created_at.format('yyyy mm dd hh m')),
  end: u.created_at,
}));
```